# Struggling to scrape a website using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I've recently started my first project in Python. I'm keen on trains, and I hadn't found any CSV data on the website of my country's rail company, so I decided to do web scraping in Scrapy. However, when using the fetch command in my terminal to test the response I keep stumbling upon DEBUG: Crawled (403). Terminal freezes when I try to fetch the second link
These are the websites I want to scrape to get data for my project:

[https://www.intercity.pl/pl/site/dla-pasazera/informacje/frekwencja.html?location=&date=2022-10-25&category%5Beic_premium%5D=eip&category%5Beic%5D=eic&category%5Bic%5D=ic&category%5Btlk%5D=tlk](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

[https://rozklad-pkp.pl/pl/sq?maxJourneys=40&start=yes&dirInput=&GUIREQProduct_0=on&GUIREQProduct_1=on&GUIREQProduct_2=on&advancedProductMode=&boardType=arr&input=&input=5100028&date=25.10.22&dateStart=25.10.22&REQ0JourneyDate=25.10.22&time=17%3A59](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Having watched a couple of articles on this problem I changed a few things in the settings of my spider-to-be to get through the errors, such as disabling cookies, using scrapy-fake-useragent, and changing the download delay. I also tried to set only USER_AGENT variable to some random useragent, without referring to scrapy-fake-useragent. Unfortunately, none of this worked.

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RetryUserAgentMiddleware': 401,
}

FAKEUSERAGENT_PROVIDERS = [
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakeUserAgentProvider',  # this is the first provider we'll try
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakerProvider',  # if FakeUserAgentProvider fails, we'll use faker to generate a user-agent string for us
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FixedUserAgentProvider',  # fall back to USER_AGENT value
]
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148'
```

I haven't written any code yet, because I tried to check the response in the terminal first. Is there something I can do to get my project going?

Answer (score 0):

Your first link is working fine, I was able to successfully extract all of the information from the table by using the spider in my example below, and no extra middleware was needed to access it.  Your second link was a dead end though both in scrapy and when attempting to visit it using the browser. You may want to double check that your URL is accurate.

```
import scrapy

class Train(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "train"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request("https://www.intercity.pl/pl/site/dla-pasazera/informacje/frekwencja.html?location=&date=2022-10-28&category%5Beic_premium%5D=eip&category%5Beic%5D=eic&category%5Bic%5D=ic&category%5Btlk%5D=tlk")


    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath("//table//tr"):
            yield {
                "train": row.xpath("./td[@headers='freq-table-header-train']/text()").get(),
                "number": row.xpath("./td[@headers='freq-table-header-number']/text()").get(),
                "category": row.xpath("./td[@headers='freq-table-header-category']/text()").get(),
                "name": row.xpath("./td[@headers='freq-table-header-name']/text()").get(),
                "from": row.xpath("./td[@headers='freq-table-header-connection_from']/text()").get(),
                "to": row.xpath("./td[@header='freq-table-header-connection_to']/text()").get(),
                "popularity": row.xpath("./td[@headers='freq-table-header-connection_popularity']/text()").get()
            }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I keep getting 403 responses and outputted JSON file is empty. I can visitthe second link, may it be that accession is dependent on location?

Comment: that is possible for the second link... did you try copying and pasting the full code?  Oh that is because the link is no good anymore you need to get a link for another date in the future....  try it with this link https://www.intercity.pl/pl/site/dla-pasazera/informacje/frekwencja.html?location=&date=2022-10-28&category%5Beic_premium%5D=eip&category%5Beic%5D=eic&category%5Bic%5D=ic&category%5Btlk%5D=tlk   I also changed it in the example

Comment: Yes, I copied your code and also updated the link :/ https://postimg.cc/WhYmdXbv JSON file is still empty

Comment: It puzzles me how you get the response with the same code

Comment: Oh... maybe its your user agent... are you using a user agent that mimics the browser?

Comment: I use scrapy-fake-useragent with code as in my post.  Do you think there is a better solution?

Comment: oh try turning off all of those extra middlewares and just use the stock settings but maybe leave the user agent one... comment out all the FakeUSERAGENTS too

Comment: I tried crawling with constant user-agent. I also used the solution presented in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bM7SMx44xgY, namely creating a list of user agents yourself and using it by a class method in DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES. Sadly, none of these worked and I keep getting 403 responses